# Find the locus of ${\arg \left( {z - 1} \right) = \pi }$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the locus of ${\arg \left( {z - 1} \right) = \pi }$

Let $B = \left\{ {z:\arg \left( {z - 1} \right) = \pi } \right\}$

$\arg \left( {z - 1} \right) = \pi  \Rightarrow \left( {x - 1} \right) + iy \Rightarrow {\tan ^{ - 1}}\left( {\frac{y}{{x - 1}}} \right) = \pi $

First case $y=0$

Arguement can either be $0$ or $\pi$

$x\ne 1$, if $x-1>0$ then Arguement is $0$

If $x\ne 1$, if $x-1<0$ then Arguement is $\pi$

Hence the locus is a straight line $y=0$ where the region $x<1$ is only required.

Is this answer correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly notice that
$$\arg(z - 1) = \pi \iff z - 1 \in \mathbb{R}_-^*$$
You can convince yourself of this result by drawing it in the complex plane.
Then, $z \in ]-\infty,1[$ so your answer is correct.